# How to append value_counts() output to the original df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

So I have the following `df`:

```
       Open      High       Low     Close  
0    0.001268  0.001277  0.001266  0.001271   
1    0.001268  0.001269  0.001265  0.001266   
2    0.001265  0.001265  0.001242  0.001254   
3    0.001253  0.001271  0.001244  0.001251   
4    0.001253  0.001259  0.001249  0.001257   
5    0.001257  0.001260  0.001241  0.001248
```

when I running this line:

```
df["Open"].value_counts()
```

I get the following output:

```
0.001253    2
0.001268    2
0.001265    1
0.001257    1
```

I was wonder how I could append this output to the original `df` to make it look like this:

```
       Open      High       Low     Close     Open_count  
0    0.001268  0.001277  0.001266  0.001271       2
1    0.001268  0.001269  0.001265  0.001266       2
2    0.001265  0.001265  0.001242  0.001254       1
3    0.001253  0.001271  0.001244  0.001251       2
4    0.001253  0.001259  0.001249  0.001257       2
5    0.001257  0.001260  0.001241  0.001248       1
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge` is your friend:

```
s = df["Open"].value_counts()

df.merge(s, left_on='Open', right_index=True,
         suffixes=['','_count'])
```

Output:

```
       Open      High       Low     Close  Open_count
0  0.001268  0.001277  0.001266  0.001271           2
1  0.001268  0.001269  0.001265  0.001266           2
2  0.001265  0.001265  0.001242  0.001254           1
3  0.001253  0.001271  0.001244  0.001251           2
4  0.001253  0.001259  0.001249  0.001257           2
5  0.001257  0.001260  0.001241  0.001248           1
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, could you please explain to me what `left_on` does

Comment: when you do `df.merge`, `df` is the left dataframe. So `left_on='Open'` matches the values in `df['Open']` to the index of `s` (`right_index=True`).

Comment: Oh, I see what confuses me a bit is the `df.merge` also has `right_on` attribute, what the difference between the two? (`right_on` and `left_on`)

Comment: You could probably suggest `groupby.transform` and count here, then avoid the merge. Although I'm not particularly thrilled of grouping on floating point values... there's a whole lot of issues with that. Although the merge here is also doing something similar...

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
df['Open_count'] = df['Open'].map(df['Open'].value_counts())
```

Output:

```
       Open      High       Low     Close  Open_count
0  0.001268  0.001277  0.001266  0.001271           2
1  0.001268  0.001269  0.001265  0.001266           2
2  0.001265  0.001265  0.001242  0.001254           1
3  0.001253  0.001271  0.001244  0.001251           2
4  0.001253  0.001259  0.001249  0.001257           2
5  0.001257  0.001260  0.001241  0.001248           1
```